# Clipping raster with shapefile and exporting each raster subset using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster, python-script-tool, extract-by-mask

I want to **clip a raster image using a shapefile with differents polygons** (each polygon have its "FID_malla" value [FID_malla is large data type]) and save the subset rasters individually with "FID_malla" name.

So if I have 50 polygons the result of the clip will be 50 raster images. To do that I use for iterator.

I run this code, but I obtain a error in SelectLayerByAttribute: **Parameters are not valid**  .
Also, I don't know if after SelectLayerByAttribute operation the code runs well.

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""

# First parameter
    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Shape recorte",
        name="in_features",
        datatype="GPTableView",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")

# Second parameter
    param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Imagen satelite",
        name="raster",
        datatype="DERasterDataset",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")

    parameters = [param0, param1]
    return parameters

def isLicensed(self):
    """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
    return True
def updateParameters(self, parameters):return
def updateMessages(self, parameters):return

def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    """The source code of the tool."""

a= parameters[0].valueAsText
b= parameters[1].valueAsText
#-----------------------------

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(a, ["FID_malla"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (a,  "NEW_SELECTION",  "FID_malla={}".format(row[0]))  

        #Execute ExtractByMask
        out = ExtractByMask(b, a)

        out.save("C:\Users\mvinuales\Desktop\Image_Chips\imagen" + "\_" + str(row[0]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Your where clause is incorrect as you had identified. A very simple check is to run the tool in Arcmap, go to geoprocessing > Results and right click on your tool and copy snippet, *then look at it*! As you will discover because your source data is a shapefile then the field delimiter needs to be double quotes, an example is shown below where bob is a shapefile:

```py
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view="bob", selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", where_clause='"FID" = 2')
```

2. You are not ending your output raster with a file extension such as `tif`, this will mean your output will be an ESRI raster, if that is what you truly desire?

Comment: I this particular case the sentence is `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(a, "NEW_SELECTION", '"FID_malla" ='+str(row[0]))`